# API works in browser but not in python

Tags: python, api

I am newbie to python and i am working on connecting a API from extracting data. The API works perfectly when using browser or VBA, but when i use python it return below error message:

> ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.github.com', port=443):
>   Max retries exceeded with url: /events (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))

Below are my codes:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
```

Does anyone know what the issue is? Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: i tried it, it works fine.

Comment: @navyad I tried to run the code by switching from my company’s network to my personal networks and it works fine.  Any idea what the cause is and how to fix? Thanks so much

Comment: you may need to add proxy in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run your code. But as per your input in comment, you are also able to run code from different VPN. So i am not sure what the problem is, just give a try to bypass https validation

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events', verify=False)
```

If it is not working, try to add https_proxy for python environment.

Comment: Thanks, finally my solution is to use pypac to get my coperate proxy pac file for sending the request